# jqGrid: How to set value of rowList as soon as the grid load first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid with the following configuration -

```
var PAGER_COMBO:[5,10,15,20,25,40,50],
var grid_default={
    rowNum: ($("#contentPanel").height()/30).toFixed(),
    height: $("#contentPanel").height(),
    rowList: jsVar.PAGER_COMBO,
 };
```

It is clear that the grid height is dynamic and it will change when the screen(monitor) size will be changed. And I have considered that each row height will be 30. So the total  rowNum of grid will be also dynamic.
And rowList is a pre-defined list.

Suppose for a big monitor the height will be 900. In that case rowNum will be
900/30=30. I want that this 30 will be added in the rowList automatically and will be default selected as soon as the grid loaded. Is it possible ?

**Update 1 :**
Attached an image for better giving better explanation of the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand your question correctly. If you want to set `rowNum` to some value, which depends from "the screen(monitor) size" then you can do this. You can just make all required calculations, and then **create the grid with the options which you want**. You can generate `rowList` which you want *before* the grid will be created and use the array as the input parameter. You can sort the items of the array, used as `rowList` parameter, and don't include duplicates. All what you need is to write some lines of JavaScript code *before* jqGrid will be created.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Let me explain that in easy way. in the rowList I have the following options {5,10,20,50} . The grid loaded with rowNum 20. I want that the record per page dropdown in the grid footer will select 20 automatically. But currently it shows 5 as selected in the select box. Please check the attached image in my question in updated section.

Comment: @Jimcarry: `rowList` should be **array**. So `{5,10,20,50}` is wrong. It should be `[5,10,20,50]`. If would would use `rowNum: 20, rowList: [5,10,20,50]` or `rowList: [5,10,20,"10000:All"]` then `20` will be selected.

Comment: You are right. Side by side i was doing another mistake. I need to be sure that the calculated rowNum is an integer value. I have done that by doing parseInt(my_row_num_value). And now its working perfectly.